# Accessing the Nelder-Mead simplex at every iteration using scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, simplex

Some background:

I am using the Nelder-Mead simplex optimization algorithm from `scipy.optimize.minimize` to do some hyperparameter optimization on a deep learning model. For an input **x** and a function **f**, `minimize` is trying to optimize the function value **f(x)** by changing **x**. In my case, **x** are the hyperparameters of the model, **f**, which is making predictions for a constant set of training examples.

Because **f** is very large, and there are many training examples, each call **f(x)** takes about 10 minutes when the embarrassingly parallel problem of making predictions on all training examples is distributed among 20 rtx-2080 GPUs. So every step is expensive.

For one reason or another (crashing, running out of time on the GPUs) the script will stop in the middle of optimizing. It is therefore desirable for me to save the state of the optimization so I can continue it from where it left off. I am able to save the hyperparameter values **x** during every N.M. step, but this only goes so far. Even if you've recovered **x** (let's call the recovered version **x'**), the Nelder-Mead simplex is lost. If you restart optimization of **f** at **x'**, `minimize` has to rebuild the simplex by evaluating **f(x' + p)** **N** times, where **p** is some perturbation to one of the dimensions of **x** , and **N** is either dim(**x**) or dim(**x**) + 1. In my case, **x** is high dimensional (>20), so it takes ~3 hours *just to recover the simplex*.

The question:

I need a way to access the simplex at every step in case of a crash. Others have suggested using a callback to solve the problem of recovering parameter and function values during optimization with `scipy.optimize.minimize` (not necessarily with Nelder-Mead). However, in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) for `minimize` it states the only version of `minimize` that can return both the current parameter values (**x**) *and* an `OptimizeResult` object (an object which could contain the simplex in the case of N.M.) via a callback is the "trust_constr" method. In other words, I'm pretty sure using a callback with the "nelder_mead" version only gives you access to **x**.

The best solution we've come up with is to edit the `_minimize_neldermead` function within the `minimize` source code to save the simplex values after each step. Is there a more elegant way of accomplishing this? Does `minimize` already have this ability and we just can't find it?

Comment: I did not analyze everything in detail, but assuming, that we are working with a black-box model here: *the function-value sequence is the only input*, i don't see much of a problem: store your x-vectors in each iteration (not just the last), also the output and when there is a need for continuation: re-simulate your *optimization path* by re-using your cached values without touching your backend, e.g. by counting function evals and comparing the count against the number of values in the cache -> use cache if available, pass-through to your backend if not (=re-calc internals with cached path).

Comment: Actually, assuming determinism in regards to scipy's internals, you won't even need to store all the x-vectors, but just the initial vector and the function-eval results. This will be enough to recover every internal bit.

Comment: I agree with the answer given in the above comments by sascha. It is just necessary to write the function f(x) so that it can make a record of the argument x and value f(x) every time it is called. The state of a Nelder Mead minimization after each iteration is the simplex and the values at each vertex. However, each iteration can require from 1 to N+1 evaluations of f(x), so the state after each evaluation is more complicated. Fortunately, it is not necessary to preserve the state if you can rerun the optimization up to the point of failure using saved evaluations.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem. The solution that works for me is to define your function `f(x)` in the normal way such that `minimize()` calls it with the input array x. But you can also provide additional arguments, such as a list or array that you can use to store your simplexes, their values, and whatever other cats and dogs your function may calculate along the way. So your function looks like this:

```
def f(x, simplex_list):
    # do math here to calculate your value. I'll use sum().
    my_val = np.sum(x)

    # Here's the magic bit. Add whatever else you want into the dict
    my_simplex = {'x': x, 'f_x': my_val}
    simplex_list.append(my_simplex)

    return my_val
```

When you call scipy.opt.minimize, your call will now look like this:

```
# initialize your simplex record stash 
simplex_list = []

# do whatever steps to figure out your first guess x0, bounds
opt_result = opt.minimize(f, x0=b, bounds=bounds, args=(simplex_list),
                          method='Nelder-Mead', 
                          options={'xatol': 1, 'fatol': 2, 'maxiter': 40}
                          )

# Now dump out the contents of simplex_list.
```

The various option values should be set appropriately for your problem. By using the `args` parameter, `minimize` knows to pass in the extra argument `simplex_list` and you are using that as your record keeping mechanism.

Just be cautious that if you later add additional arguments to `f()`, such as a directory path to write debug info to or other variables that `f()` might need to be calculated, you'll have to also add them in the proper order to your `args` parameter. If you don't, `minimize()` will quietly fail on you. I've done this to myself multiple times ... :)